# How to setup test automation for a E-commerce website?

Tags: rest, testing, automation, automated-tests, e-commerce

I have a E-commerce website magento as beckend and and frontend based on react .
I want an automation framework that can help in fulfilment of all basic use cases . If somebody already have made there own framework then help me out with this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's that basic you could just create automated UI tests yourself.
I would recommend using robot framework with the selenium library. The tests are written in python and there are plenty of courses out there to help you.

I would highly recommend this course to bring you up to speed, but you have you purchase it. https://www.udemy.com/robot-framework-level-1/learn/v4/overview

Or loads on youtube too. 
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=robot+framework+python+tutorial -

These will fulfill your basic needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you refer to is [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and [continuous delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery). There's a fairly long list of providers:

- [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/)
- [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/)
- [Drone](https://github.com/drone/drone)
- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/)

They are all declarative, you could define your own scripts and run them on their systems. All of them have guides on how to set them up and with support for magnto, reach and a longer stack.

> I want an automation framework that can help in fulfilment of all basic use cases

I don't understand what do you mean by "all basic use cases".

Comment: Basic use cases for an e -commerce is 1) Login  2) Register a new user  3) add to cart a product  4) add new address 5) payment Or can say place an order

Comment: What? What exactly do you want? A framework that magically test all your scenarios?

Comment: No my use cases are diffrent but i need a sample